# Deploy a docker container to production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, production-environment, docker

I have create a docker image on my dev machine and tested my RAILS code on it.
The container uses code from the host this way :

```
docker run -v [/path/to/dir/to/mount/on/local/machine/]:[/desired/path/in/docker/] -p [port to forward] -i -t [name of image] /bin/bash
```

Now I would like to push the container to a preproduct environment and then a production environment.

What is the best way to do that ?
Should I install docker on the preprod/prod servers and then use the image ?

Or should I configure my staging to be identitical to my image and upload my source code ?

Comment: Can you give some details about what is actually in the volume specified by `-v`? Is it some source code, some assets, something else?

Comment: are you sure you want to go to production with docker, they say it's not ready for that yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you deploying a rails app? I would take a look at [Dokku](https://github.com/progrium/dokku) which is basically a self hosted version of heroku.

If you want to use docker directly I would take a look at using a deployment script of some type to help you with this. Basically it can login via ssh, git clone the code to a directory and then run the docker image with the new directory (stopping any existing instances). But again Dokku makes this way simpler.